# counting amount of true statements in a 2d boolean array

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

To count the amount of true statements I already have a fitting code

```
public static int countTrueStatement(int posX, int posY, boolean [][]arr){
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if(arr[i][j]){
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Now I don't want to count all of the array, but only the neighbouring. E.g. if my array has a size of 7x7 I only want to count the amount of true statement from a 3x3 array from a postion I can decide. I thought abouut creating a subarray, but I'm not sure if that is the best solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
public static int countTrueStatement(int posX, int posY, int lenX, int lenY, boolean [][]arr){
    int count=0;
    for(int i=posY; i < posY + lenY; i++){
        for (int j = posX; j < posX + lenX; j++) {
            if(arr[i][j]){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Instead of starting to iterate from the beggining of the array (index 0) we start from posY,posX. similarly, we stop after lenY,lenX and not when we reach the end of the array.